# How to roundup to numbers to 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a textinput that only accept any numbers that are dividable by 500  examples 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500 3000, etc.
if the user write 12263 it should roundup to 12000 if the user write 12789 it should be rounded to 12500

I have this code, but it doesnt work at all, at some numbers work fine, but with other it just go to the max number

vPayrollBureauMaxOffer: is the max number that can be accepted i get this value from an api
vPayrollAmount:  is the amount the user writ in the textinput
3000 is the min value accepted if the user write a number less than 3000 it should change to 3000

this is my code

```
const validatePayroll = () => {
    if(vPayrollAmount <= 3000){
      return setvPayrollAmount((3000));
    }
    if(vPayrollAmount >= vPayrollBureauMaxOffer){
      return setvPayrollAmount(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ','));
    }
    if((vPayrollAmount >= 3000) && (vPayrollAmount <= vPayrollBureauMaxOffer)){
      return setvPayrollAmount(Math.floor(vPayrollAmount / 500.0) * 500.0);
    }
  };  

<TextInput
   style={styles.inputs}
   placeholder={`${vPayrollAmount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')}`}
   placeholderTextColor={theme.SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR}
   keyboardType={'numeric'}
   underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
   autoCorrect={false}
   autoCapitalize="characters"
   value={vPayrollAmount}
   onBlur={() => validatePayroll(vPayrollAmount)}
   onChangeText={setvPayrollAmount}
   />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual thing to do is divide by the multiple (500 in your case), round the result, and then multiply by the multiple:

```js
const values = [12263, 12789];
for (const value of values) {
    const result = Math.round(value / 500) * 500;
    console.log(`${value} => ${result}`);
}
```

But that does actual standard rounding, giving you 12,500 for an input of 12,263 because that's closer to 12,500 than it is to 12,000 (237 away vs. 263 away).

You can use `Math.floor` instead to always round down to the nearest multiple of 500 to get the values you've cited in your question instead:

```js
const values = [12263, 12789];
for (const value of values) {
    const result = Math.floor(value / 500) * 500;
    console.log(`${value} => ${result}`);
}
```

(Similarly if you always wanted to go the other way, there's `Math.ceil`.)

Note that you'll want to reverse `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` if dealing with negative numbers, since they always go *down* or *up* respectively, not toward 0. For instance, `Math.floor(-5.2)` is `-6`.

Answer (score -1):

Thats code is placing thousand separators only if the number is greater than max value.

Replace this line

```
return setvPayrollAmount(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ','))
```

With this one:

```
return setvPayrollAmount(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer)
```